# Does a network interface receive multicast packet that sent by itself?

Tags: networking, multicast, nic

I really need a network expert to help me. I would like to know that does a network interface receive a multicast packet sent by itself? For example, a network interface card (NIC) with IP address 192.168.52.10 sends out a multicast packet 239.255.10.1:11101, does the NIC 192.168.52.10 receive the multicast packet 239.255.10.1:11101 just sent out? If the answer is no, can I do any configuration at the NIC to receive the multicast packet sent out by the NIC itself?

There is an application in my company but it seems that the loopback function does not work, which means that the NIC does not receive a multicast packet sent by itself.

Comment: If the receiving multicast socket has loopback enabled on it, yes, otherwise no.

Comment: @user207421 I'm not a windows expert, can you tell me or show me the link about how to enable the multicast socket loopback? By the way, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `IP_MULTICAST_LOOP` option to allow outgoing multicast packets to be received on the same interface:

```
int enable = 1;
// assume "socket" is an open UDP socket
if (setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, 
               &enable, sizeof enable) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    char errbuf[300];
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, WSAGetLastError(),
                  0, errbuf, sizeof errbuf, NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "setsockopt failed: (%d) %s", WSAGetLastError(), errbuf);
}
```

Note that this also requires that the socket in question is joined to the relevant multicast group using `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` or `IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP`.